# Disable GitLab Letsencrypt as option when installing for first time

Tags: gitlab-omnibus

When I install GitLab Omnibus on Ubuntu-18.04 I am hitting a LetsEncrypt problem. The certs won't be issued.

This results in GitLab using a self-singed cert. I want to install my own certs so don't need Let's Encrypt at all.

I can disable it once GitLab is installed by adding this to /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb

```
letsencrypt['enable'] = false
```

and then adding my certs in the correct place and then reconfigure.

Is it possible to pass a gitlab.rb file into the initial installation process with the above line so it doesn't even bother with LetsEncrypt on installation?

I am installing by:

```
sudo EXTERNAL_URL=<my url> apt-get install gitlab-ee
```

so I am looking for something like:

```
sudo EXTERNAL_URL=<my url> CONFIG=<path to local gitlab.rb> apt-get install gitlab-ee
```

EDIT: I believe the initial Lets Encrypt error issue is this one:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/4900

Answer (score 7):

I took a cue from the docker installation instructions and passed the `GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG` variable like this:

```
sudo GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG="letsencrypt['enable'] = false" apt-get install gitlab-ce
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Using the GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG did not work for me, at least not with yum on rhel 7.  For a workaround, I specified an http instead of https url:

```
sudo EXTERNAL_URL=http://<my-url> yum install -y gitlab-ee  #or apt-get
```

Then change to https, disable letsencrypt, and add the certs in the configuration after the installation and reconfigure.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on a docker-compose install where it would try to use letsencrypt and fail.  I had to add letsencrypt['disable'] to the docker-compose file and that fixed it for me.:

`environment: GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: | # Add any other gitlab.rb configuration here, each on its own line external_url 'https://gitlab.example.com' letsencrypt['disable']`